# How to do a Mongo aggregation query in Spring Data?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

It's the first time I am using Mongo in Java and I am having some problems with this aggregation query. I can do some simple queries in Mongo for Spring with `@Query` annotation in my Repository interface which extends the `MongoRepository<T, ID>`. It would be helpful to know which approach to take when you do long aggregations in Spring-Data.

```
db.post.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {}
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "users",
        localField: "postedBy",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "user"
      }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {
          username: "$user.name",
          title: "$title",
          description: "$description",
          upvotes: { $size: "$upvotesBy" },
          upvotesBy: "$upvotesBy",
          isUpvoted: { $in: [req.query.userId, "$upvotesBy"] },
          isPinned: {
            $cond: {
              if: { $gte: [{ $size: "$upvotesBy" }, 3] },
              then: true,
              else: false
            }
          },
          file: "$file",
          createdAt: {
            $dateToString: {
              format: "%H:%M %d-%m-%Y",
              timezone: "+01",
              date: "$createdAt"
            }
          },
          id: "$_id"
        }
      }
    },
    { $sort: { "_id.isPinned": -1, "_id.createdAt": -1 } }
])
```

Comment: You need to use `mongoTemplate` or native MongoDB driver. Take a look this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17008947/3710490)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17008947/whats-the-difference-between-spring-datas-mongotemplate-and-mongorepository

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can implement the [AggregationOperation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/Aggregation.html)  and write the custom aggregation operation query and then use `MongoTemplate` to execute any mongo shell query you have executed in your mongo shell as below:

**Custom Aggregation Operation**

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.AggregationOperation;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.AggregationOperationContext;

public class CustomAggregationOperation implements AggregationOperation {

  private String jsonOperation;

  public CustomAggregationOperation(String jsonOperation) {
    this.jsonOperation = jsonOperation;
  }

  @Override
  public org.bson.Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext aggregationOperationContext) {
    return aggregationOperationContext.getMappedObject(org.bson.Document.parse(jsonOperation));
  }
}
```

**Any Mongo Shell Aggregation query executor**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.AggregationOperation;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.AggregationResults;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.TypedAggregation;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import sample.data.mongo.models.Course;

@Service
public class LookupAggregation {

  @Autowired
  MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

  public void LookupAggregationExample() {

    AggregationOperation unwind = Aggregation.unwind("studentIds");

    String query1 = "{$lookup: {from: 'student', let: { stuId: { $toObjectId: '$studentIds' } },"
        + "pipeline: [{$match: {$expr: { $eq: [ '$_id', '$$stuId' ] },},}, "
        + "{$project: {isSendTemplate: 1,openId: 1,stu_name: '$name',stu_id: '$_id',},},], "
        + "as: 'student',}, }";

    TypedAggregation<Course> aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
        Course.class,
        unwind,
        new CustomAggregationOperation(query1)
    );

    AggregationResults<Course> results =
        mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, Course.class);
    System.out.println(results.getMappedResults());
  }
}
```

For more details, Have a look at the [Github repository](https://github.com/krishnaiitd/learningJava/tree/master/spring-boot-sample-data-mongodb/src/main/java/sample/data/mongo/services) classes: *CustomAggregationOperation* & *LookupAggregation*

**Other approaches** also using *MongoTemplate*:

**#1.** Define an interface for your custom code for Model **Post**:

```
interface CustomPostRepository {
     List<Post> yourCustomMethod();
}
```

**#2.** Add implementation for this class and follow the naming convention to make sure we can find the class.

```
class CustomPostRepositoryImpl implements CustomPostRepository {

    @Autowired
    private MongoOperations mongoOperations;

    public List<Post> yourCustomMethod() {

      // custom match queries here
      MatchOperation match = null;
      // Group by , Lookup others stuff goes here
      // For details: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/Aggregation.html

      Aggregation aggregate = Aggregation.newAggregation(match);

      AggregationResults<Post> orderAggregate = mongoOperations.aggregate(aggregate,
                      Post.class, Post.class);
      return orderAggregate.getMappedResults();

    }
}
```

**#3.** Now let your base repository interface extend the custom one and the infrastructure will automatically use your custom implementation:

```
interface PostRepository extends CrudRepository<Post, Long>, CustomPostRepository {

}
```

Answer (score 29):

Although this is old thread, but I hope whoever found this thread can now safely for doing multi stage/pipeline aggregation(not quite sure what it's call) in MongoRepository.
As I'm also struggling looking for clue and example of aggregation in mongo repository **without mongo template**.

But now, I'm able to do the Aggregation pipeline as per spring doc said in [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.repositories.queries.aggregation)

My aggregation looks like this in mongoshell:

```
db.getCollection('SalesPo').aggregate([
    {$project: {
        month: {$month: '$poDate'},
        year: {$year: '$poDate'},
        amount: 1,
        poDate: 1
     }},
      {$match: {$and : [{year:2020} , {month:7}] 
     }}
      ,
      {$group: { 
          '_id': {
            month: {$month: '$poDate'},
            year: {$year: '$poDate'} 
          },
          totalPrice: {$sum: {$toDecimal:'$amount'}},
          }
      },
    {$project: {
        _id: 0,
        totalPrice: {$toString: '$totalPrice'}
     }}
 ])
```

While I transform it into @Aggregation annotation in MongoRepository become like this below (I'm removing the aposthrephe and also replace with method params):

```
@Repository
public interface SalesPoRepository extends MongoRepository<SalesPo, String> {

@Aggregation(pipeline = {"{$project: {\n" +
        "        month: {$month: $poDate},\n" +
        "        year: {$year: $poDate},\n" +
        "        amount: 1,\n" +
        "        poDate: 1\n" +
        "     }}"
        ,"{$match: {$and : [{year:?0} , {month:?1}] \n" +
        "     }}"
        ,"{$group: { \n" +
        "          '_id': {\n" +
        "            month: {$month: $poDate},\n" +
        "            year: {$year: $poDate} \n" +
        "          },\n" +
        "          totalPrice: {$sum: {$toDecimal:$amount}},\n" +
        "          }\n" +
        "      }"
    ,"{$project: {\n" +
        "        _id: 0,\n" +
        "        totalPrice: {$toString: $totalPrice}\n" +
        "     }}"})
    AggregationResults<SumPrice> sumPriceThisYearMonth(Integer year, Integer month);
```

My Document looks like this:

```
@Document(collection = "SalesPo")
@Data
public class SalesPo {
  @Id
  private String id;
  @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)
  private LocalDate poDate;
  private BigDecimal amount;
}
```

And the SumPrice class for hold the projections:

```
@Data
public class SumPrice {
  private BigDecimal totalPrice;
}
```

I hope this answer can help whoever ***try to do aggregation in mongorepository without using mongotemplate***.

Comment: how do you handle null parameters?

Comment: @saran3h sum mongodb out of the box handle null value (or non numeric value) to zero. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum

Comment: Hi,thanks for the answer,but i have some confusion:
1.is there a better way writing query json in @Aggregation?It is annoyed by parsing query string with the line-break pattern and quotation marks.

Comment: 2.Is it possible not defining a class to retrieve the aggregation result?Because the result may contain many reference documents.and i have to define them all to do this.For example, i already defined some entities mapping to the collection.and they are refer to each other by using array of objectids.and i do aggregation to return a whole matching complete document which will replace objectids to real documents.To retreive the final document,i have redefine the whole entity tree with nothing changed except replace objectid array to a nested entity array.is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: updating:for question 2 ,  i work out with using JSONObject ,Object or BasicDBObject to retreive the aggregation result.Like this:`AggregationResults<JSONObject> result = someRepository.doAggregate(id)`

Comment: I am getting a weird result back. I get aggregateResult with 2 items, but both items are empty. Tried with JSONObject, didnt work either.