# Convert mongoDB query into Spring Data MongoDB java code

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have the following MongoDB query and I dont know how to convert in Spring Data java code, the `group` and `replaceRoot` operations.

```
db.getCollection('operationData').aggregate([

    { $match: type: "OPERATION_CHEAP", amount: {$gte: 1000}, 
              createdAt: {$gte: ISODate("2020-01-24T23:00:00.000Z")}
    },

    { $project: { amount: 1, operationId: 1 } },

    { $sort: { amount: -1 } },

    { $group: { _id: '$operationId', g: { $first: {data: '$$ROOT'} }} }, <----
        
    { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: '$g.data' }}, <------
            
    { $sort: { amount: 1 } }

])
```

This is the code for the match operation:

```
 Criteria criterias = new Criteria()
            .andOperator(Criteria.where(Operation.AMOUNT)
            .gte(minAmount)
            .and(Operation.TYPE).is(OperationTypeEnum.CHEAP_OPERATION)
            .and("createdAt").gte(startDate).lte(endDate));

 MatchOperation matchOperation = Aggregation.match(criterias);
```

This is the code for the project operation:

```
ProjectionOperation projectionOperation = Aggregation.project("amount", "operationId");
```

And this is the Aggregation operation:

```
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(matchOperation, projectionOperation,
                                                     sort(direction, "amount"));
AggregationResults<OperationDataVO> aggregate = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, 
                                                     COLLECTION, OperationDataVO.class);
```

I cant find out how to create and integrate the `GroupOperation`

Comment: A useful workaround when you have an aggregation that works in the mongo shell, but you don't know how to convert it to a Spring aggregation : https://stackoverflow.com/a/59726492/5873923

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
Aggregation.group("operationId").first("$$ROOT").as("g");
Aggregation.replaceRoot("g");
```