# Spring Mongo find if two field values are not equal

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I have the following json

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5fd0b6d2db14e72272560029"),
"fooId" : "",
"fooNames" : [],
"fooDetails" : [ 
    {
        "foId" : "5fd0b63ddb14e7227255fffb",
        "fooSubId" : "5fd0b6d2db14e72272560029"
    }
],
...
```

I need to pull out the results of those documents whose `_id` is not equal to the nested object `fooDetails.fooSubId`.

How can I do this in spring Mongo?

--UPDATE--
For example below given are the entries in my collection

Entry one

```
 {
        "_id": ObjectId("5fd0b63ddb14e7227255fff1"),
        "fooId": "",
        "fooNames": [],
        "fooDetails": [
          {
            "foId": "5fd0b63ddb14e7227255fffb",
            "fooSubId": "5fd0b63ddb14e7227255fff1"
          },
        ]
      }
```

Entry two

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5fd0b63ddb14e7227255fff2"),
    "fooId": "",
    "fooNames": [],
    "fooDetails": [
      {
        "foId": "5fd0b63ddb14e7227255fffb",
        "fooSubId": "5fd0b63ddb14e7227255fff3",
        
      }
    ]
  }
```

Entry three

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5fd0b63ddb14e7227255fff2"),
    "fooId": "",
    "fooNames": [],
    "fooDetails": []
  }
```

The result should filter out the first one, it should give only the following two:

Result one

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5fd0b63ddb14e7227255fff2"),
    "fooId": "",
    "fooNames": [],
    "fooDetails": [
      {
        "foId": "5fd0b63ddb14e7227255fffb",
        "fooSubId": "5fd0b63ddb14e7227255fff3",
        
      }
    ]
  }
```

Result two

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5fd0b63ddb14e7227255fff4"),
    "fooId": "",
    "fooNames": [],
    "fooDetails": []
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need a query similar like this:

Is only update the field `fooDetails` using `$set` and `$filter`.

With `$set` the field is replaced and with `$filter` you can look for objects into array which `fooSubId` is equal to the `_id`.

So, every object into array where `fooSubId` is not equal `_id` will not be in the array.

Edit, using `$toObjectId` to compare equal objects:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    "$set": {
      "fooDetails": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$fooDetails",
          "as": "id",
          "cond": { "$eq": [ {"$toObjectId": "$$id.fooSubId"}, "$_id" ] }
        }
      }
    }
}])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rc8moG5doEM)

With this query, you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59697496/how-to-do-a-mongo-aggregation-query-in-spring-data) answer todo into Spring.

Comment: I tried the same but its giving empty results!

Comment: Try to use `$toObjectId`. I'm gonna update my answer

Comment: I tried this as well, still giving empty results

Comment: I have updated the question with an example, incase if my question is not clear.