# How to write mongo cli query in mongo-template for $in aggregation

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

This is how my data looks like

```
{
        "_id" : "2011250546437843117",
        "name" : "Book",
       
        "textbook" : [
                "Maths",
                "Science"
],
       "language" : [
                "English"
        ],
         "isRead" : true,
        "isAvailable" : true
        
}
```

I have to filter documents based on textbook,and based on that isRead field should be true or false.
my mongo query is

```
db.user.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
          "isAvailable": true
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      
      "textbook": 1,
      "name": 1,
      "isread": {
        $in: [
          "Maths",
          "$textbook"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

I have tried to write this using mongo-template

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(match(Criteria.where("isAvailable").is(true)),
project("textbook","name"));
```

I dont understand how to write the $in operator in project stage.

Thankyou in advance.

Comment: similar question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59697496/how-to-do-a-mongo-aggregation-query-in-spring-data