# Convert the aggregation query of mongodb for spring boot

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have a mongodb query which works fine

```
db.user.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "data": {
        "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "data.v": {
        $regex: "Mohit Chandani"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

It basically, get all the document having the value Mohit Chandani and here is the output:

```
{ "_id" : "b387d728-1feb-45b6-bdec-dafdf22685e2", "data" : { "k" : "fullName", "v" : "Mohit Chandani" } }
{ "_id" : "8e35c497-4296-4ad9-8af6-9187dc0344f7", "data" : { "k" : "fullName", "v" : "Mohit Chandani" } }
{ "_id" : "c38b6767-6665-46b8-bd29-645c41d03850", "data" : { "k" : "fullName", "v" : "Mohit Chandani" } }
```

I need this query to be converted for my spring boot application and I am writing the following:-

```
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(Aggregation.project(Aggregation.ROOT), Aggregation.match(Criteria.where(connectionRequest.getWord())));
```

It would be helpful to know which approach to take when you do long aggregations in Spring-Data.

Comment: For what it’s worth, your aggregate query may work fine but I highly doubt it performs well because of the multiple pipelines for just a regex query on a field. Also $unwind pipeline stage tends to slow down operations a bit since there’s a bit of effort required to unfold all the documents in an array.

Comment: what you mean by "convert for my spring boot application"?

Comment: @deadshot I need the query to be executed through the spring boot application and not from the mongodb shell.

Comment: @chridam yes I get your point

Comment: this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/59726492/9050514

Comment: Does the answer help you?

Comment: @varman The main issue is I don't know about any fields I have just database uri and I want to perform a search operation in all the databases and want the fields collection and database which contains that "string". Do you have any idea of how to return if there is no .class present of that collection name.

Comment: So do you know the fileds that you need?

Comment: @varman No I just have the databse uri                                          
   `MongoIterable<String> collections = database.listCollectionNames();`                  
  This is how I am getting the collection name present in the database

Comment: I wonder, if you dont know the fields, how can you do aggregation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help you, Hope you are using `MongoTemplate` for aggregation.

```
@Autowired
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
```

And the code for above script is

```
public List<Object> test() {

    Aggregation.newAggregation(
        project().and(ObjectOperators.valueOf(ROOT).toArray()).as("data"),
        unwind("data"),
        match(Criteria.where("data.v").regex("Mohit Chandani")
        )
    ).withOptions(AggregationOptions.builder().allowDiskUse(Boolean.TRUE).build());

    return mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(YOUR_COLLECTION.class), Object.class).getMappedResults();

}
```

I'm not sure the `project()` of above code would work, because I haven't tried it. I referred it form [Spring data mongodb](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.aggregation.supported-aggregation-operations)

If it doesn't work, this would definitely work. Few opetaiotion are not suppored in spring data like `$addFields`, `$filter`.. So we do a [Trick to convert](http://pingax.com/trick-convert-mongo-shell-query-equivalent-java-objects/)

```
public List<Object> test() {

    Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
        
        p-> new Document("$project",
                new Document("data",
                    new Document("$objectToArray","$$ROOT")
                )     
            ),
        unwind("data"),
        match(Criteria.where("data.v").regex("Mohit Chandani"))     

    ).withOptions(AggregationOptions.builder().allowDiskUse(Boolean.TRUE).build());

    return mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(YOUR_COLLECTION.class), Object.class).getMappedResults();

}
```