# How to get random record from one collection MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I have entity `Article` I'm trying to retrieve one random record from database collection.

This is entity `Article`:

```
@Data
@Document(value = "article")
public class Article {

    @Id
    private String articleId;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String fullArticle;
```

This is service to save it:

```
@Override
public Article save(Article article) {
    return articleRepository.save(article);
}
```

And repository:

```
@Repository
public interface ArticleRepository extends MongoRepository<Article, String> {
}
```

So, now I'm trying to create a method that will get me one random record from my collection `Article` also, I want to create a controller so when I go to some endpoint and submit some get method to retrieve one record from the collection and so I can check it in postman or with Swagger. I find some answers to similar question to mine but no one solved my problem, I want to have API for something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$sample](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/) in an aggregation query to get a random document:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$sample": {
      "size": 1
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7k1ClbSsWDv)

I've tested the code and it works as expected.

You can create add this method into repository:

```java
@Aggregation(pipeline={"{$sample:{size:1}}"})
AggregationResults<Article> random();
```

And call from service like this:

```
@Override
public Article random(){
  return articleRepository.random().getMappedResults().stream().findFirst().orElse(null);
  // also you can use .orElseThrow() or whatever you want
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but on which way I can implement that so I can use it on some endpoint and etc.?

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62865095/13464279). I can't test now but `@Aggregation(pipeline = {/*the query*/})` should works. Also I'll try to test in a while and post an example.

Comment: Edited question added repository and service methods.